# No module named livelossplot

Tags: python, pip

I have recently tried to make some realtime plots for my Ml models.
I have installed livelossplot through this command:

```
pip install livelossplot
```

But, when trying to import the module in Jupyter, it returns error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'livelossplot'
```

Please, 
can someone help me?

Comment: how did you install jupyter? through anaconda ?

Comment: yes, i've installed jupyter through anaconda

Comment: then you must  install inside the anaconda environment for it to take effect

Comment: What do you mean @Albin Paul by installing the package inside Anaconda environment?

Comment: i have added an answer hope this clarifies what i said

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `keras` - kindly do not spam the tags (removed); also please *format* your code (done for you, this time...)

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

**pip install livelossplot==0.1.2**

Refer the below link
https://pypi.org/project/livelossplot/0.1.2/

If it doesn't work then you can clone the below repository

https://github.com/stared/livelossplot

Comment: @Vincent. If this solved your problem could you please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well there are a couple of ways to go about this problem one way is to start anaconda-navigator

[image]

> left click on the play type button there in the (base)root environment and select open in terminal

and then simply type

```
pip install livelossplot
```

One another method is if you have added anaconda path to you PATH variable in linux or environment variable in WINDOWS then you can log into the environment

like

```
albin@computer:~$ source activate
(base) albin@computer:~$ pip install livelossplot
```

if you havent added to the PATH or environment variable then you can log into the enviroment by specifying the full path like

```
albin@computer:~$ source anaconda3/bin/activate 
(base) albin@computer:~$ pip install livelossplot
```